# Opening Jupyter Notebook in python 3.8.8 in Windows 10

Tags: jupyter-notebook, anaconda, spyder

I have installed Anaconda. I want to open Jupyter notebook in python 3.8.8 in Windows 10

I ran ***conda install spyder-notebook -c spyder-ide*** in Anaconda cmd and I am getting ***All requested Packages already installed.***

Even after restarting the Spyder, I am not able to see the Notebook option in view pane.

What more should I do so that I can open and run Jupyter notebook in Spyder

Comment: What is the Spyder version you have installed? To use the `spyder-notebook` plugin you need to install Spyder 4.x . The plugin dependencies and versions are listed here: https://github.com/spyder-ide/spyder-notebook#dependencies

Comment: I have sypder 3.8.8 which comes with Anaconda. How can I install 4.x in Anaconda

Comment: I think your Python version is 3.8.8 (Spyder 3.8.8 doesn't exist). To check the Spyder version you have you can do `conda list`. For you to use/check the `spyder-notebook` plugin maybe you could create a new environment and install there the correct version of Spyder along side the plugin with something like this: `conda create -n spyder-env spyder=4 spyder-notebook -c conda-forge`. Then to activate the new environment `conda activate spyder-env` and then to run spyder just type `spyder` (the lauched instance should list the notebook plugin)